# Sampling from a categorical distribution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, random-generation

I am confused by these lines of code:

https://github.com/openai/maddpg/blob/master/maddpg/common/distributions.py#L174

```
def sample(self):
    u = tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(self.logits))
    return U.argmax(self.logits - tf.log(-tf.log(u)), axis=1)
```

This is supposed to sample from a categorical distribution.

You can ignore the `tf` that prepends the commands (these are basically tensorflow commands)

The function receives a vector of [logits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit).

The first line takes the shape of the logits vector (`self.logits`) and samples a vector of independent random values from a uniform distribution on  $[0,1]$.

The second line is what really confuses me. Why the $\textsf{logits} - \log(-\log(x))$ and substracting from the logits?

My first intuitive approach would have been going from logits to probability.. What is going on there?

Comment: What is a "vector of logits"?

Comment: A vector where each element is a logit:   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Let me unravel your question to remove all the not-so-relevant fluff around it.*

> Given a tuple of $n$ values of the form $(p_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$, where each $p_i\in(0,1)$, the question is to characterize the distribution of the following process:
>
> 1. Draw independent random variables $U_1,\dots,U_n$ uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$
> 2. Return $$\arg\!\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \left( \log \frac{p_i}{1-p_i} - \log\log\frac{1}{U_i}\right)$$

What we will show:

> The output of this algorithm is a categorical random variable $Z$ such that
>   $$
> \forall i\in [n], \quad \mathbb{P}\{ Z = i\} \propto \frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\,. \tag{$\dagger$}
> $$

---

**Detailed proof.**

For every $1\leq i\leq n$, let $$X_i \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \log \frac{p_i}{1-p_i} - \log\log\frac{1}{U_i} = - \log\left(\frac{1-p_i}{p_i}\log\frac{1}{U_i}\right)\,.$$

By a standard result, we have that
$\log\frac{1}{U_i}$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $1$, and therefore (by properties of the exponential distribution) this implies that
$$
Y_i \stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{1-p_i}{p_i}\log\frac{1}{U_i} \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i})\,.\tag{1}$$

Now, since 
$$
\arg\!\max_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i = \arg\!\max_{1\leq i\leq n} (-\log Y_i) = \arg\!\min_{1\leq i\leq n} Y_i\tag{2}
$$
we have that the output $Z$ of the algorithm has probability mass function
$$
\forall i\in[n],\quad\mathbb{P}\{Z=i\} = \mathbb{P}\{ Y_i = \min_{1\leq j\leq n} Y_j\} = \frac{\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{p_j}{1-p_j}} \tag{3}
$$
using e.g. the result [from this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2635295/75808) for the last equality.

In other term,

> The output of the algorithm is $i$ with probability proportional to $\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}$.

---

**Alternative.** if you don't care about the derivation, here is the quick and simple explanation: this is called the *Gumbel trick*. If $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, then $-\log\log\frac{1}{U}$ has a standard [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution). And you can use the following theorem *(well-known, I reckon, to whoever knows it)*

> **Theorem.**  If $G_1,\dots,G_n$ are independent standard Gumbel r.v.'s, and $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n > 0$, then the random variable
>   $$
> X = \arg\!\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(\log \alpha_i + G_i)
> $$
>   takes values proportional to the $\alpha_i$:
>   $$
> \forall i\in [n], \quad \mathbb{P}\{X=i\} \propto \alpha_i\,.
> $$

See e.g. [this](https://casmls.github.io/general/2017/02/01/GumbelSoftmax.html) for more.

Comment: @purpletentacle You're welcome! I did learn a few things in the process of answering.

Comment: I think it is worth adding a link to this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01144