# Weighted winner selection in distributed lottery

Tags: probability

I have a question that emerged from a programming problem: I need to select a winner among $n$ participants with probability proportional to integer weights $w_1,\dots,w_n$. Each participant can generate uniform random variables, but I cannot combine these variables or pick among them. Importantly, this means I can't just use one uniform random variable and pick a winner according to $\frac{w_j}{\sum_i w_i}$.

My current approach is to have every participant $i$ generate $w_i$ random variables $u_{i,1},\dots,u_{i,j},\dots,u_{i,w_i} \sim U(0,1)$ $\forall i, j$ and then pick the winner according to who has the highest number $i^*=\arg\max_i \max_j u_{i,j}$. But this requires $O\left(\sum_i w_i\right)$ computations. My question is whether there is a way to get this down to $O(n)$.

So I'm looking for some transformation $f(u,w)$ that takes the weight $w_i$ of one participant (*edit*: it would be ok to also use the total $\sum_i w_i$, but if it can be avoided, great) and one uniform random variable $u_i$ for that participant and transforms it $v_i = f(u_i,w_i)$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(v_i \ge v_j \forall j \in 1,\dots, n\right) = \frac{w_i}{\sum_j w_j}$$

My first thought was to just multiply $f(u,w)=u\cdot w$, but that doesn't work: if we have two participants with weights $w_1=1$ and $w_2=2$, then $v_1 \sim U(0,1)$ and $v_2 \sim U(0,2)$, but $\mathbb{P}(v_1\ge v_2) = 0.25 \ne 1/3$.

Comment: It seems like you are looing for a way to efficiently sample from a categorial distribution with given probabilities $p_i$. Look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359442/sampling-from-a-categorical-distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single random uniform, $u_i$, from each participant, select

$$\arg\max_i\bigg(\frac{\log(u_i)}{w_i}\bigg)$$

Or equivalently,

$$\arg\max_i\Big(u_i^{1/w_i}\Big)$$

Testing with a quick simulation in R:

```
n <- 6L
w <- 1:n
tabulate(max.col(t(matrix(log(runif(1e6L*n)), n)/w)), n)/1e6
#> [1] 0.047665 0.094986 0.142365 0.189983 0.238822 0.286179
tabulate(max.col(t(matrix(runif(1e6L*n), n)^(1/w))), n)/1e6
#> [1] 0.047389 0.095431 0.142469 0.191077 0.238128 0.285506
w/sum(w)
#> [1] 0.04761905 0.09523810 0.14285714 0.19047619 0.23809524 0.28571429
```

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Reparametrization_tricks)

Comment: thank you! should this be $\arg \min$ instead of $\max$?

Comment: No. $\log(u_i)<0$, so larger $w_i$ will tend to be be less negative (larger).

Comment: ah right, thank you!